# Kivy's app crashing when opened. Cannot find request moudle altough I imported it via buildozer spec file

Tags: python, android, python-requests, kivy, kivy-language

My application is just crashing on Android, but when its on PC everything is fine. I found the crash report, and I will link it. It says the request library is not here, although it is and it was imported.
I compiled with `buildozer`.

I already tried to compile it 5 times. The other times it crushed immediately this time it took 10 seconds of black screen. also it shows the "Python for android ended." line in the crush report 5 times and in the others just 1. I did put all the modules in spec., and I will put link for the crash file and the spec. and the app files. I have no idea why it is crashing.

To see the crashing times search "Python for android ended."
(the file was pretty big so I uploaded it)
The crash file:
    https://vacation-revolution.com/codeexample/log
The spec file:
    https://pastebin.com/XWjY8YSL
The kv file:
    https://pastebin.com/zLeyLhA5
The .py file:
    https://pastebin.com/Pi3SqBnV

for example some of the crashfile:

```
11-07 01:25:50.486  1320  1381 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
11-07 01:25:50.535  1320  1381 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
11-07 01:25:50.564  1320  1381 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
11-07 01:25:50.564  1320  1381 I python  :    File "/home/osboxes/Desktop/App/Another_try/aa/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 15, in <module>
11-07 01:25:50.564  1320  1381 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
11-07 01:25:50.564  1320  1381 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

The app just crashed after 10-15 seconds. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I see `OSError: Label: File 'Arial.ttf' not found`. Try removing your `font_name` lines from your `.kv` file.

Comment: Early in your log, I see the `No module named 'requests' `, but in the last execution of your app, I see many lines showing that Python was extracting the `requests` module. It looks to have died due to the font file not found

Comment: Thank you! it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the font. I just added the font file into the folder and in the .spec i added the ttf ending.